# MySQL Replication -- are queries ever modified by master?

Tags: mysql, performance, replication

I have some applications that were developed with some extremely slow queries of the form:

```
INSERT INTO x (SELECT ... FROM y WHERE ...)
```

The slow part in the query is the SELECT (temp table, etc).

I've been considering doing master-master replication in the hopes that the replication works in some way that atomizes the INSERT into individual INSERTs, such that only the server that the query is directly executed on takes the performance hit. Does it work this way? If not, what is a good way of working around these queries, short of re-writing them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried row based replication? This only applies the row changes from the master to slave and doesn't re-do the query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-formats.html